# Search Multiple Strings (from File) in a file and print the line

Tags: python, file, search, keyword

Again apologies for been noob here: Trying below code for searching multiple strings read from keywords and search in `f` and printing the line.
It works if I have only one keyword but not if I have more then one.

```
keywords = input("Please Enter keywords path as c:/example/ \n :")
keys = open((keywords), "r").readline()
with open("c:/saad/saad.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if (keys) in line:
            print(line)
```

Comment: Could you provide an input and an expected output?

Comment: What is the format of this keyword file? A bunch of words on a single line separated by spaces?

Comment: keywords ("aa","bb") :
 file contains line like (aa is good , bb is very good , cc is not good):
expected output as :
aa is good
bb is very good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the challenges of looking for keywords is defining what you mean by keyword and how a file's contents should be parsed to find the full set of keywords. If "aa" is a keyword, should it match "aaa" or maybe ""aa()"? Can a keyword have numbers in it?

A simple solution is to say that keywords are alphabetic only and should match contiguous alphabetic strings exactly, ignoring case. Further, matches should be considered line by line, not sentence by sentence. We can use a regex to find alphabetic sequences and sets to check containment like so:

*keys.txt*

```
aa bb
```

*test.txt*

```
aa is good
AA is good
bb is good
cc is not good
aaa is not good
```

*test.py*

```
import re

keyfile = "keys.txt"
testfile = "test.txt"

keys = set(key.lower() for key in 
    re.findall(r'\w+', open(keyfile , "r").readline()))

with open(testfile) as f:
    for line in f:
        words = set(word.lower() for word in re.findall(r'\w+', line))
        if keys & words:
            print(line, end='')
```

Result:

```
aa is good
AA is good
bb is good
```

Add more rules for what you mean by a match and it gets more complicated.

**EDIT**

Suppose you have one keyword per line and you just want a substring match (that is, "aa" matches "aaa") instead of a keyword search, you could do

```
keyfile = "keys.txt"
testfile = "test.txt"

keys = [key for key in (line.strip() for line in open(keyfile)) if key]

with open(testfile) as f:
    for line in f:
        for key in keys:
            if key in line:
                print(line, end='')
                break
```

But I'm just guessing what your criteria are.

Comment: i have tried this but having couple of issues ;
1 . for some reason it doesnot search anything if keywords are entered one each line like
aa
bb
cc
if i put key words in one line then it only return bb
2. secondly what if i want to return 'aaa' as well if 'aa' keyword is searched

Comment: then you need a different [regular expression] for the `re.findall()` function.

Comment: Input files can have many formats and its impossible to cover all of the possibilities. You could put samples in your question like I did in my answer. For one key per line, you could read the file line by line, strip out whitespace then filter empties like `keys = [key for key in (line.strip() for line in open(keyfile)) if key]`. To match `"aaa"`, you do a substring search instead of a regex.

Comment: thanks @tdelany finally it worked , just one more request if u can break this  line , i am having a bit issue de coding it
keys = [key for key in (line.strip() for line in open(keyfile)) if key]

Comment: You can read and strip each line with `[key.strip() for key in open(keyfile)]`. But if the file has an empty line, one of the keys will be an empty string. So, you could check each key with `[key.strip() for key in open(keyfile) if key.strip()]` or you could add a generator `(key.strip() for key in open(keyfile))` to only do the strip once.

Answer (score 0):

```
keywords = input("Please Enter keywords path as c:/example/ \n :")
keys = open((keywords), "r").readline()
keys = keys.split(',')  # separates key strings
with open("c:/saad/saad.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        for key in keys:
            if key.strip() in line:
                print(line)
```

You are reading the line in as one string.  You need to make a list of each comma separated string.  Then test each key for each line (removing whitespace around the key)

This is assuming your keyword file is something like: aa is good, bb is good, spam, eggs

Answer (score 0):

```
#The Easiest one...
def strsearch():

  fopen = open('logfile.txt',mode='r+')

  fread = fopen.readlines()

  x = 'Product Name'

  y = 'Problem Description'

  z = 'Resolution Summary'

  for line in fread:

      #print(line)

       if x in line:

           print(line)

       if y in line:

           print(line)

       if z in line:

           print(line)
```

strsearch()