# How do I shrink this if using regex?

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

How on earth do i shrink this monstrosity:

I´m using python 3

```
if "arME" in file or "deDE" in file or "enUS" in file or "esES" in file or "ptBR" in file or "itIT" in file:
```

Comment: Is this python and why would you use regex?

Comment: oh my god i forgot, im using python 3, sorry for that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search Multiple Strings (from File) in a file and print the line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37902523/search-multiple-strings-from-file-in-a-file-and-print-the-line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically one would use an alternative regex:

```
p = re.compile('arME|deDE|enUS|esES|ptBR|itIT')
if p.search(file):
    ...
```

The `A|B` in a regex means match either `A` or `B`, where `A` and `B` are arbitrary regexes. It can be extended to an arbitrary number of regexes.